# Is some blood during cat delivery normal?

Tags: cats, breeding

My cat is delivering and I see some blood, seemingly originating from the vaginal canal, not very much. Is this normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some fluid isn't abnormal, there will be a small amount at the start as she discharges the vaginal plug prior to birthing the first kitten. During the process, she will chew off the umbilical cords of each kitten. Finally, as her uterus contracts there will be some additional fluid discharged.

Observation, post delivery, is important though. If you continue to see a bright, red, bloody discharge continue or she shows signs of disinterest or lethargy, unwillingness to eat, then it may be wise to contact a vet for advice. Don't stress though, cats have been doing this for thousands of years without our help. :)

Comment: Seeing her eat the afterbirth was gross

Comment: @Viziionary: It's efficient. It keeps the nest clean, and it recaptures the energy and nutrients she spent building that structure. After all, at that point in the process it's just a lump of leftover meat; might as well not waste it.

Answer (score 1):

Bleeding a little during birth is perfectly normal so don't worry and it will also be mixed with amniotic fluid from the kittens so it may look like there's more blood than there actually is. When my cat was giving birth to her kittens she would bleed a little after/between each one. just as long as it is bright red and not dark or a brownish colour then she's perfectly fine.